# How to generate a sequence of random numbers in given ranges?

Tags: android, dart, random, probability

I'm trying to generate a list of 10 random numbers.
I have some ranges like:

0. 0 to 9
1. 10 to 99
2. 100 to 999
3. 1000 to 9999
4. 10000 to 99999
5. 100000 to 999999.

If I generate a random number in a (min, max) range where `min = 0` and `max = 999999` with this code

```
import 'dart:math';
final _random = new Random();
   
int next(int min, int max) => min + _random.nextInt(max - min);
```

a number between 100000 and 999999 is more likely to be generated than a number between 0 and 9. This is because there are more numbers in the range (100000, 999999) than in the range (0,9). If I pick a random number from 0 to 999999, it's more likely that is a number in the range `5)`.

I would like to generate 10 random numbers in the given ranges with equal probability for each range.

Comment: Using the random number generator, determine what range you're generating (e.g. labelling each range from `0` to `5`, generate a number between those inclusively). Then use the generator again to generate a random number within the selected range.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-do-i-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java)

Comment: @Rogue That could be a good solution. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry @PeterO. but the answer does not seem to take into account the probability for each different range.

Comment: 2 things are not clear to me in your question: 1) why `nextInt(max - min)` in your code instead of the `nextInt(max)`? 2) not really clear what exactly you mean in `a number between 100000 and 999999 is more likely to be generated than a number between 0 and 9.`. The probability density is ~uniform in the range.

Comment: Java or Dart? Fix your tags.

Comment: @AlexanderArendar
1) Because in this way I can also choose to start from a range other than range 0);
2) Yes, the probability is uniform within every single range, but not uniform in the total (from 0 to 999999). I edited the question to clarify this point.

Answer (score 0):

I'd pick the range first, then find the number in that range.

Consider:

```dart
var _rnd = Random();
int inRanges() {
  var powerOfTen = _rnd.nextInt(6);
  var min = pow(10, powerOfTen) as int;
  var max = min * 10 - 1;
  if (min == 1) min = 0; // The cases are not completely symmetric.
  return min + _rnd.nextInt(max - min);
}
```